# In place upgrade on a Windows 2003 with Certificate services

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, certificate-authority

I'm looking to do an in-place upgrade for 2 Windows 2003 servers domain controllers running certificates to Windows 2008 R2. Will it work, has anyone tried this, and will I need to do anything with certificate services afterwards?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you one and all. I'll take a look through these links and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things to consider here.

1. Certificate Services should not be running on a domain controller.
2. 2008 R2 is x64 only. If your 2003 servers are x86, there is no in-place upgrade path:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979563(v=ws.10).aspx
3. <strike>In-place upgrading domain controllers is not supported. Directory Services should be uninstalled before a server is in-place upgraded.</strike>
4. Certificate Services *can* be on a server has had its OS upgraded in place.

---

So you can do a few things assuming your 2003 is x64.

1. <strike>Install new DCs. Demote the current DCs.</strike> In-place the OS and follow this link on how to upgrade AD CS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742388(v=ws.10).aspx
2. Backup and restore the CA config to new servers (also outlined in that link above). Remove AD CS from the domain controllers. In-place the servers that you migrate AD CS to.
3. Stand up a new PKI on new servers according to best practice with an offline root and AD CS running on **dedicated** servers that don't have any other roles installed. Revoke your currently issued certs. Uninstall AD CS from your old CAs. Re-issue certs from your new PKI.

---

Edit: As Ryan points out - in-placing the DCs *are* supported. I'm 100% positive that this was not always the case, but it seems to be now, which makes things slightly easier for you. I would still recommend migrating Certificate Services off of your DCs still.

Comment: Mark, one thing, I don't agree with your point #3 about in-place upgrades of domain controllers not being supported, assuming you're upgrading from a supported version: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732825(v=WS.10).aspx As well as http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/upgrade-domain-controllers-to-windows-server-2008-r2(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_SupportedUpgrade which has a section specifically titled "Supported in-place upgrade paths" ... "In-place upgrades from Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2003 R2 to Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2 are supported"

Comment: @RyanRies there was a technet article that stated that you should demote the DC, then upgrade, then promote it again. Of course, now that you've linked to those contrary articles I can't find it and I'm on mobile with a butternut squash and pecan dish on my lap :(

Comment: I *need* to be right on this because if I'm not, I've created a *crap*-ton of unsupported DCs in my career... ;)

Comment: I think its probably better practice to demote, upgrade (or clean install) then promote than to upgrade in place, but of course having other roles on the DC greatly complicates doing that, which is why an upgrade in place is supported.